# Creating custom module: yo meanjs:crud-module with a custom schema/model?

Tags: mean-stack, mean, meanjs

```
yo meanjs:crud-module
```

generates a module similar to 'articles' modules.

Is there a way to generate module from a custom model/schema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator is only a starting point for your module.

When creating the module, start from the back and edit your way to the front:

```
modules/articles/server/models/articles.server.model.js
```

change the schema to fit your requirements. The controllers and routes on the server side don't need any changing. Then you move to:

```
modules/articles/client/views/view-articles.client.view.html
```

Here you add new inputs that matches your schema. After that you should be done with your 'custom model/schema'. Hope this helps.